# PyQt5: Closeable tabs in QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have been trying to implement QTabWidget section in my application, and would like to be able to close the tabs if needed.

I read that I need to set the setTabsCloseable flag to true and add a pyqtSignal but I cannot do so because QObject has no connect attribute.
On the contrary most examples I have found online, mention the use of QtCore.QObject.Connect()

here is a minimum reproducible example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys, os


class Dialog_01(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog_01,self).__init__()

        mainWidget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
        # QtCore.QObject.connect(self.chatView, QtCore.SIGNAL('tabCloseRequested(int)'), self.closeTab)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)


        myBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)

        self.tabWidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(),'Tab_01')        



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use `self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can super the QtabWidget to incorporate custom functionality and also keep things wrapped up nicely.

I have found it quite common to override classes to suit certain programs with PyQt /Pyside and I strongly suggest you get into the habit!

```
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtWidgets
    import sys, os

    class QCustomTabWidget (QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
        def __init__ (self, parent = None):
            super(QCustomTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setTabsClosable(True)
            self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab) # connect to method to close
            for i in range(1, 10): # add tabs here
                self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 'Tab %d' % i)

        def closeTab (self, currentIndex):
            currentQWidget = self.widget(currentIndex)
            currentQWidget.deleteLater()
            self.removeTab(currentIndex)


    class Dialog_01(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Dialog_01,self).__init__()

            mainWidget=QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
            mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)

            self.tabWidget = QCustomTabWidget()
            mainLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)


            myBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.tabWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)

            self.tabWidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QTextEdit(),'Tab_01')   #also add tabs here
            self.tabWidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QTextEdit(),'Tab_02')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
        dialog_1.show()
        dialog_1.resize(480,320)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that I should subclass, but I think it should be okay without subclassing for now. Your answer helped alot along with @eyllanesc 's comment!

Comment: @ellanesc is the master of PyQt.. He was the one that taught me such skills :P

Comment: He helped me loads during my first small project in PyQt, and now again when I moving to a bigger project. Its nice to have someone so skilled, that sometimes lack of complete documentation is okay.

Comment: You should have a look at PySide (QT for Python) .. it is new but now officially supported by QT.. The API is practically the same as PyQt.. only import from pyside.. you can even write code that can run from either using imports. https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/

Comment: So I can convert to pyside by just switching imports? What are the benefits?

Comment: I do'nt know the current status but some bindings only work in one or the other.. There are differences in licensing if you do anything commercial.. one might be cheaper.  The Pyside project has been running for 5 years now and has opensource input as well as official support from Qt themselves.. I find the documentation a little better and more online resources.  PyQt is written by 1 guy i think (or so the story goes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212178/discussion-between-johnashu-and-blaine).